# Can't get dynamic input to be validated with jQuery validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have read most of questions that have been answered about this issue but till now can't get it to work, for 2 days now, I have this form

```
<form id="mr_project_form" class="post" role="form">
    <label class="fre-field-title" for="fre-project-title">Your project title</label>
    <input class="input-item text-field" id="fre-project-title" type="text" name="post_title" placeholder="Add more than 15 characters"/>
    <!--Submit button-->
</form>
```

And i can apply the validator on the input element here,like this

```
$( "#mr_project_form" ).validate();
```

Then after an AJAX call an input injected by AJAX response,So the form would be something like this

```
<form id="mr_project_form" class="post" role="form">
    <label class="fre-field-title" for="fre-project-title">Your project title</label>
    <input class="input-item text-field" id="fre-project-title" type="text" name="post_title" placeholder="Add more than 15 characters"/>

    <!--Inserted input-->
    <input class="input-item text-field" id="inserted_input" type="text" name="inserted_input"/>
    <!--Submit button-->
</form>
```

And as mentioned in [#22287410](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287410/jquery-validation-for-dynamically-created-fields) and [#18022224](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022224/jquery-validation-plugin-doesnt-validate-dynamically-created-form-elements), I should add the rule after the element been added, so in the ajax success i added the rule like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: mr_ajax_url,
  type: "POST",
  data: dataString,
  success: function (response) {
    $("#" + insertLcation).html(response);
    $('#inserted_input').rules('add', { digit: true, });
  },
});
```

But it can't be validated, and i get this error on pageload

> TypeError: t.validator.methods[a] is undefined; can't access its "call" property
>
> TypeError: s is undefined; can't access its "form" property

Comment: what is `insertLcation` ?

Comment: @ewwink This AJAX insert html into different places, so i created a function that accepts a location and then do ajax, and it works fine,but the problem is that the inserted fields can't be validated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its `digits` with `s`, not `digit`.

```
$('#inserted_input').rules('add', { digits: true, });
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, it worked, but still getting the second error, do you know why?

Comment: cannot replicate the error, I can't `s` in your code.